# Exception thrown while running BIRT report using BIRT API

Tags: report, birt

Unable to open a connection with the database connection profile.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1897)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.infy.ceh.management.birt.controller.TestBirtAPI.executeReport(TestBirtAPI.java:59)
    at com.infy.ceh.management.birt.controller.TestBirtAPI.main(TestBirtAPI.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.wereDefaultDriversCreated(DriverManager.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.resetDefaultInstances(DriverManager.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.(DriverManager.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.getInstance(DriverManager.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.getDriverDefinition(DriverConnectionBase.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.initializeJDBCConnection(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.SQMConnectionFactory.createConnection(SQMConnectionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SEVERE: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.dbprofile.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1897)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at com.infy.ceh.management.birt.controller.TestBirtAPI.executeReport(TestBirtAPI.java:59)
    at com.infy.ceh.management.birt.controller.TestBirtAPI.main(TestBirtAPI.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.wereDefaultDriversCreated(DriverManager.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.resetDefaultInstances(DriverManager.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.(DriverManager.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.DriverManager.getInstance(DriverManager.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.getDriverDefinition(DriverConnectionBase.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.initializeJDBCConnection(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.SQMConnectionFactory.createConnection(SQMConnectionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory loadFontMappingConfig
INFO: load font config in jar:file:/D:/DailyTasks_2016/october/ESHLib/lib/deployment-jars/birt-runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime_3.7.0.v20110615-1818.jar!/fontsConfig.xml cost 16ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/ja/X11/fonts/TT cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_13/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/ru.ansi-1251/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_15/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:52 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in d:/windows/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in C:/windows/fonts cost:918ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/truetype cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/ar/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in e:/WINNT/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in C:/WINNT/fonts cost:1ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_2/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/tt cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/th_TH/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_8/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_7/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/share/fonts/truetype cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in f:/WINNT/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/ko.UTF-8/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in g:/WINNT/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_5/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in f:/windows/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in d:/WINNT/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/share/fonts/ko/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/zh_TW/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in e:/windows/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/share/fonts/zh_TW/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/share/fonts/ja/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/zh_CN.GB18030/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/share/fonts/default/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/X/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/euro_fonts/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/hi_IN.UTF-8/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/zh.GBK/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:1ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/OTF cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/iso_8859_9/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/zh_TW.BIG5/X11/fonts/TT cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/ko/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/zh_HK.BIG5HK/X11/fonts/TT cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/KOI8-R/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/openwin/lib/locale/zh/X11/fonts/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in /usr/share/fonts/zh_CN/TrueType cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory$3 run
INFO: register fonts in g:/windows/fonts cost:0ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory loadFontMappingConfig
INFO: load font config in jar:file:/D:/DailyTasks_2016/october/ESHLib/lib/deployment-jars/birt-runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime_3.7.0.v20110615-1818.jar!/fontsConfig_win32.xml cost 5ms
Nov 08, 2016 4:01:53 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.pdf.font.FontMappingManagerFactory loadFontMappingConfig
INFO: load font config in jar:file:/D:/DailyTasks_2016/october/ESHLib/lib/deployment-jars/birt-runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime_3.7.0.v20110615-1818.jar!/fontsConfig_pdf.xml cost 6ms

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be your data source type.

See : [explanation](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781961/)